# Tkinter: Remove white border outside Canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making an application using **Tkinter** and I am facing some problem.
This is a simple code in which I want to remove **white border** outside **Blue Canvas**.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.config(bg='black')
root.geometry('500x500')
Canvas(root, bg='blue', bd=0).pack(pady=100)
root.mainloop()
```

[This is output GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vjZv.png)

Here, I have tried **bd=0** to make border size **0.** But it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

add `highlightthickness=0`

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.config(bg='black')
root.geometry('500x500')
Canvas(root, bg='blue', bd=0, highlightthickness=0).pack(pady=100)


root.mainloop()
```